# SDWebImage returning -1100

Tags: objective-c, image, sdwebimage

I am trying to fetch an image using SDWebImage but it is returning a -1100 error. I am not able to figure out why:

```
[eventImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2350/2605722927_8cf675a249_b.jpg"] completed:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL * _Nullable imageURL) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }];
```

The error description:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1100.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check app transport security settings, and try using an HTTPS URL.

Comment: Thanks @StevenOjo

Answer (score 0):

Its not your issue, its server issue.

-1100

kCFURLErrorFileDoesNotExist

NSURLErrorFileDoesNotExist

The file operation failed because the file does not exist.

Thanks

Comment: The file does exist. If you go to the following URL in browser, you'd notice that it is valid: `http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2350/2605722927_8cf675a249_b.jpg`